# Сохранение файла бд из проводника Operation not permitted Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

Пытаюсь сохранить файл бд из проводника - выдаёт ошибку:
Device File Explorer
There were errors downloading files and/or directories:
secure_mkdirs failed: Operation not permitted

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Pixel 6 api 28 android 9 x86

Подскажите как решить?

Comment: вроде ж пишет, что ошибка в загрузке файлов и/или в директории!?? доступ есть в папке?

Comment: Пишет Operation not permitted - видимо нет, как можно дать доступ?

Comment: посмотри в свойствах директории, может у тебя там стоит галочка только для чтения

Comment: @стасевич подскажите как это можно сделать? Не сильно шарю в андроид студио

Comment: я в андройде вообще ничего не знаю, но у меня была проблема в спринге, ему надо было создать файлы в c:\window\temp а моя винда доступ не давала, я создавал папку c:/temp и в ide в настройках проекта указывал путь к папке с временными файлами. для этого в ide во вкладке Run->edit configuration-> там есть поле для ввода program arguments и туда вводил путь для java к пакпе для управления временными файлами по средствам комманды `-Djava.io.tmpdir=c:\temp`